# I would like to create a new variable with the Unique occurences and their Frequency in R

Tags: r

beginner and while i have attempted to search for an answer to this problem none seem to offer the solution that applys. it might be a simple one but i seem not to hack it. i have this data frame

```
df <- data.frame(FROM = c("A","A","A","B","D","C","A","D"), 
                 TO = c("B","C","D","A","C","A","B","C"))
```

I would like to create a new data frame with an extra variable call it "FREQ" with all the unique values of "FROM" and "TO" Such that the new data set Looks like this. I would appreciate some assistance.

```
df2 <- data.frame(FROM = c("A","A","A","B","D","C"),
                  TO = c("B","C","D","A","C","A"),
                  FREQ = c(2,1,1,1,2,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `dplyr` package, you can use `count`, which is a short cut for `group_by(FROM, TO) %>% summarise(n = n())` and count the number of rows for each group:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% count(FROM, TO)

#Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
#Groups: FROM [?]

#    FROM     TO     n
#  <fctr> <fctr> <int>
#1      A      B     2
#2      A      C     1
#3      A      D     1
#4      B      A     1
#5      C      A     1
#6      D      C     2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'FROM', 'TO', we get the number of elements in each group (`.N`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(FREQ = .N) ,.(FROM, TO)]
#   FROM TO FREQ
#1:    A  B    2
#2:    A  C    1
#3:    A  D    1
#4:    B  A    1
#5:    D  C    2
#6:    C  A    1
```

---

Another option is `tally()` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(FROM, TO) %>%
   tally()
#    FROM     TO     n
#   <fctr> <fctr> <int>
#1      A      B     2
#2      A      C     1
#3      A      D     1
#4      B      A     1
#5      C      A     1
#6      D      C     2
```

---

Or using `table` from `base R`, we just get the frequency of the dataset, convert to `data.frame` and remove the 0 elements in 'Freq' with `subset`.

```
subset(as.data.frame(table(df)), Freq !=0)
```

Comment: thanks i had got to the point of unto when i forgot had not subset the Data set after adding the subset to my code i got the result. However i have more than one method to it. this code worked for me.  ` df3 <- subset(as.data.frame(with(df, table(FROM, TO))), Freq !=0) `

Comment: **Thanks**  for the code,  i forgot to  subset the Data on my trial code . After adding the subset to my code i got the result. However you gave more than one method to my task. this code also worked for me too.  ` df3 <- subset(as.data.frame(with(df, table(FROM, TO))), Freq !=0) `